# Translating Recursive C Function into Y86 Assembly

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, y86

Im new to programming in assembly and I am trying to convert a function that is written in c in to assembly code Y86. This is what I have but I know that it is wrong. I started off with writing the assembly code for one parameter but then when I try to have 2 parameters I get confused on what to do. I could use some help. Lets say x = 5 and y = 1.

```
int rec_mult (int x, int y){
    if(y==1){
       return x;
    }
    else{
       return x + rec_mult(x, y-1);
    }
}

esi = x and ecx = y    
rec_mult:
    pushl %ebp
    rrmovl %esp,%ebp
    mrmovl 8(%ebp),%ecx 
    mrmovl 12(%ebp),%esi
    irmovl $1,%edx      
    rrmovl %ecx,%eax    
    subl %ecx,%edx      
    je rec_multend

    rrmovl %ecx,%edi
    irmovl $1,%edx      
    subl %edx,%edi      

    pushl %ecx      
    pushl %edi      
    call rec_mult       
    popl %edi
    popl %ecx

    addl %esi,%eax  

rec_multend:
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: I don’t have a y86 compiler to test, but one apparent issue is that you don’t preserve `%esi` before making your recursive call, and then the called function clobbers it.

Comment: The simplest solution to this problem would be to move the `mrmovl 12(%ebp),%esi` instruction after the recursive call, but before you first use `%esi`.